# Rebinding onbeforeunload event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, onbeforeunload

I am using the onbeforeunload event to confirm closing the window

> `$(window).on('beforeunload', confirmClose);`

The problem is that I use the UpdatePanel in my page and when there is an ajax postback the onbeforeunload event stop working. I found the pageLoad event handler and I tried to use it to rebind the event but I did not succeed.
This is my javascript code

```
function pageLoad(sender, args)
{
   if (args.get_isPartialLoad())
   {
       $(window).on('beforeunload', confirmClose);
   }
}
```

In this function I can execute javascript code after the postback but I couldn't rebind the event.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What happens if you remove the `if` condition?

Comment: The same result, in fact I am able to execute code inside the if statement but the bind doesn't work